# bootstrap tabs not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

The bootstrap website does not do a great job of explaining how to get the tabs to work. I have looked at a few similiar questions here on stack but havent been able to fix my problem. Here is my html code:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>90 Minute IPA</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Leopard - Clean & Responsive HTML Template">

    <!-- FAVICON & ICONS -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-ie7.css">
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- CSS --> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- Responsive CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css"> 
    <!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>  

    <!-- JAVA SCRIPT -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.tweet.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.quicksand.js"></script>
    <script src="js/superfish.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script></head>
    <script src="myJava.js"></script>
    <script src="beerPageScripts.js"></script>


            <body>
        <div class="boxedWrap">

            <!-- HEADER -->
            <header>
            <div class="container"> 
            <div class="row">
                <!-- LOGO -->
                <div class="span3">
                    <a href="index.php"><img src="logo3.png" alt="Leopard"></a>
                </div>
                <!-- End LOGO -->
                <div class="span9"> 
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar pull-right visible-phone" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                      <span class="icon-align-justify"></span>
                    </a>
                    <!-- NAV --> 
                    <div class="nav-collapse">

            <nav id="primary-nav"> 
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a> </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="beerPortfolio.php">Beer Portfolio</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="beerMap.php">Brewery Map</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="tastePortfolio.php">Taste Profile</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Statistics</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="breweryStats.php">Brewery</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="styleStats.php">Style</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="tasteStats.php">Taste</a> </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Discover</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="tasteDiscover.php">Top Taste </a></li>
                                        <li><a href="topBreweries.php">Top Breweries </a></li>
                                        <li><a href="topBeers.php">Top Beers </a></li>
                                        <li><a href="topStyles.php">Top Styles</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="blog.html">Friends</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html">Settings</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                        </div>
                    <!-- End NAV -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </header>

             <!-- CONTAINER WRAPPER -->
                <div id="content" class="container">

                    <div class="row">


        <!-- RIGHT CONTENT -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/twitterbootstrap/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.raty.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#tabbable a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
})

</script>

<style type="text/css">
        .form{
            $('.form').show();    display: none;
        }​

    </style>

            <div class="span9">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="span9 space">
                        <h3 class="title">90 Minute IPA</h3> 
                    </div>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    <div class="span4 space">
                        <img src = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/brewerydbapi/beer/qqTzHb/upload_mGIvsJ-medium.png">
                    </div>

                    <div class="span5 space">
                        <p> <strong>Brewery: </strong> Dogfish Head Craft Brewery</p>
                        <br>
                        <p> <strong>Style: </strong> Imperial or Double India Pale Ale</p>
                        <br>
                        <p> <strong>ABV: </strong> 9 %</p>
                        <br>
                        <p> <strong>IBU: </strong> 90</p>
                        <br>
                        <p> <strong>Glass: </strong> Snifter</p>
                        <br>
                        <p> <strong>Average Rateing: </strong> 4</p> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                $('#cancel-custom').raty({
                    cancel:         false,
                    cancelHint:     'remove my rating!',
                    cancelPlace:    'left',
                    hintList:       ['Bad', 'Poor', 'Regular', 'Good', 'Awesome!'],
                    start: 4 ,
                    click: function(score, evt) {

                        updateRate(score,3,'qqTzHb')
                    }
                });

            });
                </script>   
            <br>
            <p><strong> Your Rating: </strong>
            <div id="cancel-custom" >   </div> </p>
                </div> <!-- end information box --> 

                     <div class="span9 space">
                        <!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render. -->
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium"></div>

<!-- Place this tag after the last +1 button tag. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>




          </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="span9 space">
                    <div class="tabbable">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Description</a></li>
                            <li class="active"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Taste Profile</a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                                <p><strong>Description: </strong> Esquire Magazine calls our 90 Minute IPA., "perhaps the best I.P.A. in America." An Imperial I.P.A. brewed to be savored from a snifter. A big beer with a great malt backbone that stands up to the extreme hopping rate.

90 Minute IPA was our first continually-hopped beer, which is a method of hopping that allows for a pungent, but not crushing hop flavor. Since introducing the world to the continual-hopping method with our 90 Minute IPA, we've since released a continually-hopped 60 Minute IPA, 120 Minute IPA and even a 75 Minute IPA (a cask-conditioned blend of 60 & 90 Minute IPAs).

In addition to the continual-hopping 90 Minute IPA recieves during the boil, we also utilize our 'Me So Hoppy' device to dry-hop the beer during conditioning (check it out in the video below).

This beer is an excellent candidate for use with our Randall The Enamel Animal filter!</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                                <p>Yummy, tastes go here</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    </div></div>    <!-- end span9-->                        
            </div> <!-- end row -->

            <!-- SIDEBAR -->
            <div id="sidebar" class="span3">


                    <form name="input" action="search.php" method="get">
                        <div class="input-prepend">
                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" name="s"  id="s" placeholder="Beer Search" />
                        </div>
                    </form>

                <div class="textWidget">
                    <h6>Stats</h6>
                    <p><strong>Beer Count: </strong> 182 </p>
                    <p class="center"> &nbsp;</p>
                    <p><strong>Brewery Count: </strong> 83 </p>
                    <p class="center"> &nbsp;</p>
                    <p><strong>Style Count: </strong> 50 </p>
                    <p class="center"> &nbsp;</p>
                    <p><strong>High ABV: </strong> 18 </p>
                    <p class="center"> &nbsp;</p>
                    <p><strong>High IBU: </strong> 120 </p>
                    <p class="center"> &nbsp;</p>

                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- End SIDEBAR -->
           </div>



    </div> 
    <!-- End CONTAINER -->

    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <footer>
        <!-- FOOTER WIDGETS -->

        <!-- End FOOTER WIDGETS -->
        <div id="footerBottom">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span4">
                    © Copyright 2012 by <a href="index.html">Beer Portfolio</a> All Right Reserved.
                    </div>
                    <div class="span8 hidden-phone">
                        <!-- SECONDARY NAV -->
                        <nav id="secondary-nav"> 
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                <li><a href="logOut.php">Log-Out</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                        <!-- End SECONDARY NAV -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- End FOOTER -->

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: Please declare all the js files at the bootom of your page, rather than in head section . All the custom javascript or jquery code should be written after that . You have them written in between the html lines which is a wrong code writing practice .

Comment: Also , if you are using the main Bootstrap javascript file , you dont need to declare the tab.js again in your html and is unnecessary . Since the main file contains all the required javascript until unless removed .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this code , you are using a class "tabbable" as an id .

```
    $('#tabbable a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
    })
```

Created a Jsfiddle for you **[Jsfiddle -Tabs example](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/QgfsB/)**

Comment: your code helped. I have them working but when the page first loads neither tab has its info showing. Once I click on the buttons it works fine. Here is the code on the first load:

http://pastebin.com/87kWnkZj

Comment: Figured it out, I didnt add fade in active to the class for my first tabs content. Works great now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great! If you encounter any problem ... do let us know .. ENjoy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You should include

```
<script src="js/tabs.js"></script>
```

within head
and remove **class="active"** from second `<li>`, Js will add it ones you click on that tab
...and one more thing is
add "fade" class next to "tab-pane"

```
i.e. 
class="tab-pane fade"
```

you could fine tabs.js here

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js

Comment: yes, min.js should be their, but also tabs.js needs to be their

Comment: bootstrap.min.js or bootstrap.js contains all the components by default until the user remove it while downloading or just want to use a specific file for the purpose.

Comment: @Chandrakant he does not need tabs.js